# ASP.NET MVC 3: How to look for the controller instead of file when id is file name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, download, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've encountered with some strange problem. It's strange for me because I don't understand it and because before everything worked fine. So, my task is to call for controller and pass it file name (with extension) and controller should recognize this file, write into log and then return the file itself if it exists (in Downloads folder). What I'm doing:

```
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Files(string id)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(string.Format("~/Downloads/{0}", id)));
        string serverPath = Url.Content(string.Format("~/Downloads/{0}", id));
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //return to the error controller
        }
        string mem = "text/html";
        if (ext == ".zip")
        {
            mem = "application/x-zip-compressed";
        }
        else if (ext == ".html" || ext == ".htm")
        {
            mem = "text/html";
        }
        else if (ext == ".pdf")
        {
            mem = "application/pdf";
        }
        //Save info about downloads into DB
        repStat.SaveStatInfo(id, HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
        HttpContext.Request.UserHostName, HttpContext.Request.UserAgent);
        return File(serverPath, mem, id);
    }
}
```

There is part of the Global.asax:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

It doesn't have more "ignores".

So, the problem is when I'm doing the call: mysite.com/download/files/test.pdf the server returns me "Page not found". Of course there is no such file in download/files path! It should call for the controller but not the real file. As soon as I delete the extension like mysite.com/download/files/test the server calls for the controller. I don't understand why it doesn't recognize the file name just as parameter and tries to find the file.

There is absolutely the same behaviour if I try to do with other controllers - as soon as parameter doesn't have any extension it works good else the server looks for the file.

The most strange thing is everything works good locally but doesn't work on the server (worked not tool long but then stopped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks strange to me too. A workaround would be to encode the dot (.) like, for example,

```
test.pdf -> test++pdf
```

and then decode it then decode it back.

Probably not the best solution, but will certainly solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I can solve the problem just specifying the path like mysite.com/downloads/test.txt - in this case this file will be found. What is strange is why in this case the asp.net mvc as if doesn't understand that it should look for a controller, not a real file. I start thinking maybe the server side is configured improperly, something wrong with asp.net.

Comment: I would like to add information. I can see there is Microsoft-IIS/6.0 on the server and as soon as the request doesn't have extension the response is normal: "X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET" BUT if I add the extension it become "Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET"

Comment: If you specify the file directly you might loose the chance to confirm if the file exist and, for example, returning an alternative page that searches for similar files or whatever. Anyway, if that serves your purpose, cool! What the newly added information, that just confirms the requests are understood differently. Maybe because of the dot, the IIS6 only looks for a file and doesn't even consider that you want a control. Not sure...

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I need to log the info, so I did how you suggested and at least it works fine, thanks for the idea! But I would like to know exactly, what's going on here... I've found some explanation how it would work (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx) but it exactly doesn't work in such way.